# KQL Join for Dissimilar permutations

Tags: azure, kql, azure-sentinel

I am having a problem where I want to join two schema with different permutations of coulmns i.e

Two tubulars Network Events and Remote URL
Join

```
https:/Holiday.com/page1    https://www.Health.com/page3
https://www.Health.com  https://www.gift.com/page3
www.gift.com    https://www.Holiday.com/page3
```

So that these match on domain

Any help would be much appreciated

I have tried diffrent join types such as:

inner
outer
semi

Comment: To clarify your question, try providing a full sample of the input (in tabular form) and the matching desired output (in tabular form). At the moment, without those, your question isn't clear

Comment: Thank you for your reply - so the URLs in the edit of the question I would like to match on domain?

Answer (score 1):

```
let NetworkEvents = datatable(url:string)
[
'https://www.Health.com/page1',
'https://www.Health.com/page3',
'https://www.gift.com/page3',
'https://www.facebook.com/page2'
];
let RemoteURL = datatable(remoteurl:string)
[
'www.facebook.com',
'www.Health.com',
'www.gift.com'
];
let URL_list = toscalar(RemoteURL | summarize make_list(remoteurl));
NetworkEvents
| mv-apply remoteurl = URL_list on (where url contains remoteurl)
```

The above query matches the `url` column in the `NetworkEvents` table with the `remoteurl` column in the `RemoteURL` table.

**Output**:

| url | remoteurl |
| --- | --- |
| https://www.Health.com/page1 | [www.Health.com](http://www.Health.com) |
| https://www.Health.com/page3 | [www.Health.com](http://www.Health.com) |
| https://www.gift.com/page3 | [www.gift.com](http://www.gift.com) |
| https://www.facebook.com/page2 | [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) |

The query uses the  `mv-apply`  operator to apply a subquery to each element of a multi-value column, that is to each element of the  `URL_list`  column, which contains a list of remote URLs from the  `RemoteURL`  table. The  `where`  clause is used to filter the  `NetworkEvents`  table based on whether the  `url`  column contains any of the remote URLs in the  `URL_list`  column using the  `contains`  operator.